# Confused about the PrintStream out variable

Tags: java, system.out, printstream

The Java documentation [page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html) for the System class says that one of its fields is called "out":

static PrintStream out

If I then look at the doc [page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) for the PrintStream class, it says that one of its inherited fields is called "out".  If I then click on this particular "out hyperlink" on that doc page, it provides a bit more detail:

protected OutputStream out

I'm confused about these two variables called "out".  Are they two *completely* seperate variables?

Comment: Why bother reading this kind of obscure documentation, everyone knows the `System.out` is the standard outstream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are they two completely seperate variables?

Yes, they are. `PrintStream` is a `FilterOutputStream`. As such it wraps an `OutputStream` object so that it can add behavior to it.

```
System.out
```

is referencing a `PrintStream` object [that is wrapping the `OutputStream` (referenced by its own `out` field)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilterOutputStream.html#out) that represents the standard output.

Answer (score 0):

Of course they're completely separate. They're in different classes. QED

They also have different types.